# scalar subquery in if statement Condition in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, conditional-statements, scalar-subquery

I have an If Statement block similar to the below which is failing with the error -
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following....

```
Begin
    If (select count(*) from Table1) > 0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Test');
    end if;
end;
```

I have similar Case statement which works fine

```
select 
case 
    when (select count(*) from Table1) > 0
        then 2
    else
        1
end
from dual
```

From what i have read in Oracle Documentation the if and when support a Boolean Expression, any ideas whether Subqueries are supported in If Conditions.

**Note:** The Statements have been simplified, i am not really going to get the count of the entire table, so no optimization suggestions please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't use a SELECT in the way you want.

In your example using CASE, you are not using a CASE "statement" -- you are using a CASE **expression**, which happens to be embedded within a SQL statement.  You can use a subquery in that case because it's within the context of a SQL statement, not a procedural statement.  You wouldn't be able to use a subquery like this in a procedural CASE statement.

Comment: I looked up the syntax for IF and CASE at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/if_statement.htm#sthref2791 and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm#sthref2511, both of them had a boolean expression for the condition that needs to be used.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  I'm saying the difference isn't between IF and CASE, it's between CASE used as a procedural statement and CASE used as an expression within a SQL statement.

Comment: Dave, I got you, I forgot the CASE usage differences in SQL and PL/SQL. So i guess using CASE in PL/SQL in the same way should fail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE

Quick example

```
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.DISABLE;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Disabled');
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enabled');
END;
```

Comment: I guess i was not clear on what was failing, i edited the question to put that information. I was having a PL/SQL error thrown, there is no issue with dbms_output.

Comment: PLS-00103 errors are normally related to syntax errors; if you put a select 'test' into the if statement does that work ?Cant get onto an oracle box today to test it myself (only have sqlserver on my laptop)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe subqueries are supported in IF conditions... PL/SQL will be expecting the SELECT to give it a set of records, not a single value to be used in a expression/statement.