# How to use Subquery Select statement as IF condition?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
if 0 <> (select count(*) from sung where hakbun = 1)then
cnt := cnt+1;
end if;
```

I tried to above source and Oracle shows blow error

> PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Get value of select in a variable and compare that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810919/scalar-subquery-in-if-statement-condition-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing the whole thing in a single query?  Does this work?

```
select cnt + (case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) into cnt
from sung
where hakbun = 1;
```